# Angular translate decimal numbers

Tags: angularjs, gettext, angular-gettext

I  am using angular-gettext for a project. I was wondering if somehow I could translate decimal numbers. FX in some languages you write 2.5 and some other 2,5. Do you have any idea if this is doable via the angular-gettext?

What other workaround could there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-gettext doesn't do this for you, but if you combine it with the built-in `$locale` service from Angular.JS, it should just work. What you're looking for is the `number` filter.